# jquery validate form in dialog before submit form

Tags: php, jquery, validation

Currently I have a set of fields on a page.  When the button is clicked, and the validation for these fields pass, a dialog modal box will appear.  This box has a few other fields that must be filled in before the form can be submitted.

How can I show that the first set of fields are validate and open the dialog with out submitting the form until the dialog fields have also been validated?

```
$( "#check-button" )  
    .button()  
    .click(function(e) { 
         // Section 1 
         $(':text, select, textarea').each(function() {  
             if ($(this).val().length == 0) {  
                     $(this).css('border', '2px solid red');  
                     e.preventDefault();  
             }  
         });  

         //Section 2
         //e.preventDefault();
         //$('#my_form').submit();
         //$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

I have tried commenting both above sections out.  Section 1 leaves everything highlighted and does not submit my form.  Section 2 submits my form with out the second items being validated.  The inputs for both sections are part of the same form.  Please let me know if there is something else I should explain about this situation.

In summary, I am looking for a way to validate each item based on id and once the first set has passed, open the dialog, allow the user to enter in the second set and validate the second set of fields.  Finally, submitting the form.

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Check out ValidForm; it implements JQuery which does everything for form validation. Google it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to just create a validate function and `return true;` if all fields look good, otherwise `return false;` ...if it returns true, then you show the dialog box.

A quick example for you (I made my own variation, but you should get the idea): http://jsfiddle.net/iwasrobbed/acU4Q/1/

By the way, if you're checking for 0 length on the field, make sure you use `trim()` so you remove any whitespaces.  The way you currently have it, pressing the spacebar once will actually mean the input is valid even though the field is blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind whatever behavior you want to the submit action of a form.  Here's how I would do it if the form is going out over AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form#first").submit(function() {
    if (validate(this)) { $("form#second").show(); }
    return false; // to prevent the form from going to your server
  });
  $("form#second").submit(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    if (validate(form)) {
      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        data: form.serialize() + $("form#first").serialize(),
        type: form.attr("method"),
        dataType: "script"
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

Basically, if the first form is valid, you open up the second form.  Then if the second form is valid, you submit the data from *both* forms.

If you want to do this synchronously, my understanding is that you can set the `async` option for `$.ajax` to `false` and and `dataType` action to `"html"`, though I've never done that myself.